# How to stream zip before closing writer

Tags: go, stream, minio

I have written a small script downloading data from MinIO, zipping them and uploading the created zip file.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go/v7"
    "github.com/minio/minio-go/v7/pkg/credentials"
)

type File struct {
    ObjectInfo minio.ObjectInfo
    Object     io.Reader
}

func downloadFiles(minioClient *minio.Client, ctx context.Context, bucketName string, directoryNames []string, fileCh chan<- File) {
    defer close(fileCh)

    for _, directoryName := range directoryNames {
        objectCh := minioClient.ListObjects(ctx, bucketName, minio.ListObjectsOptions{
            Prefix:    directoryName,
            Recursive: true,
        })

        for objectInfo := range objectCh {
            object, err := minioClient.GetObject(ctx, bucketName, objectInfo.Key, minio.GetObjectOptions{})

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }

            fileCh <- File{
                ObjectInfo: objectInfo,
                Object:     object,
            }
        }
    }
}

func zipFiles(zipWriter *zip.Writer, fileCh <-chan File) {
    for file := range fileCh {
        fmt.Println("Writing ", file.ObjectInfo.Key)

        writer, err := zipWriter.Create(file.ObjectInfo.Key)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        if _, err := io.Copy(writer, file.Object); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
}

func uploadZip(minioClient *minio.Client, ctx context.Context, bucketName string, zipObjectName string, buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    reader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())

    if _, err := minioClient.PutObject(ctx, bucketName, zipObjectName, reader, int64(reader.Len()), minio.PutObjectOptions{}); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    endpoint := "play.min.io"
    inputBucketName := "unitelmed"
    outputBucketName := "unitelmed"
    directoryNames := []string{"GENERAL"}
    zipObjectName := "my-files.zip"

    minioClient, err := minio.New(endpoint, &minio.Options{
        Creds: credentials.NewStaticV4("Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F", "zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG", ""),
        Secure: true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    fileCh := make(chan File)

    go downloadFiles(minioClient, ctx, inputBucketName, directoryNames, fileCh)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)
        defer zipWriter.Close()

        zipFiles(zipWriter, fileCh)
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    uploadZip(minioClient, ctx, outputBucketName, zipObjectName, buf)
}
```

As far as I could get it work the `zipWriter` needs to be closed before uploading the zip file. This is at least blocking memory in the size of the zip (and probably even more).

Is there a way to stream the data from the source to the zip writer and further on to the drain? In my imagination this will block only a few MB in memory.

Comment: You cannot stream zip files as they are written, the same way you can a `gzip` file, for instance, because a zip file contains an index, that depends on knowing the full contents of the file before that index can be written.